# Display the value of a node outside the scope in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode

I am reading node values from XML file and want to display the data outside the XML reader scope. But whenever I'm trying it's giving me an error.

```
try
    {
        string filename = Server.MapPath("~") + "/Blah" + "/Blah.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(filename);

        XmlNodeList Email = doc.GetElementsByTagName("EmailTo");

        foreach (XmlNode node in Email)
        {
            XmlElement MailElement = (XmlElement)node;

            string User1= CDBInteract.formatSQLInput(MailElement.GetElementsByTagName("User1")[0].InnerText);
            string User2= CDBInteract.formatSQLInput(MailElement.GetElementsByTagName("User2")[0].InnerText);

        }

        #region Mail Sending 

        dtrecord = (DataTable)ViewState["datatable"];
        Utils util = new Utils();
        string Body = "";
        if (dtrecord.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            DataView dv = dtrecord.DefaultView;
            dv.Sort = "FamNmae";
            DataTable Dts = dv.ToTable();


            string SUName = CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("SUName"));
            string SUEmail= CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("SUEmail"));
            string SmtpClient = CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("SmtpClient"));
            string EmailTo = CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("EmailTo"));
            string BCC= CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("EmailTo"));
            int m = util.SendMail(SUName , SUEmail, EmailTo, BCC, SmtpClient, "Blah", Body);

        }
```

Here I want the values from User1 and User2 to be displayed in the field of EmailTo and BCC.

Can someone guide me through it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the exact scenario, but declaring User1 and User2 outside the foreach loop might help? This is assuming that there is always going to be one record for each of them.

Comment: when I do that, it gives me another error 'use of unassigned local variable'

Comment: try declaring like this
   string User1="";

Answer (score 0):

Try like below, It will help you..

```
           try
            {
                string filename = Server.MapPath("~") + "/Blah" + "/Blah.xml";
                XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
                doc.Load(filename);    
                XmlNodeList Email = doc.GetElementsByTagName("EmailTo");
                dtrecord = (DataTable)ViewState["datatable"];
                foreach (XmlNode node in Email)
                {
                    XmlElement MailElement = (XmlElement)node;    
                    string User1 = CDBInteract.formatSQLInput(MailElement.GetElementsByTagName("User1")[0].InnerText);
                    string User2 = CDBInteract.formatSQLInput(MailElement.GetElementsByTagName("User2")[0].InnerText);
                    Sendemail(dtrecord, User1, User2);
                }               

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }


       //Create a separate method for sending email
       private void Sendemail(DataTable dtrecord, string emailto, string bcc)
        {
            try
            {
                Utils util = new Utils();
                string Body = "";
                if (dtrecord.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    DataView dv = dtrecord.DefaultView;
                    dv.Sort = "FamNmae";
                    DataTable Dts = dv.ToTable();
                    string SUName = CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("SUName"));
                    string SUEmail = CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("SUEmail"));
                    string SmtpClient = CDBInteract.formatInput(ReadConfigSettings.Get("SmtpClient"));
                    string EmailTo = emailto;
                    string BCC = bcc;
                    int m = util.SendMail(SUName, SUEmail, EmailTo, BCC, SmtpClient, "Blah", Body);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally called the function within the scope of the reader. And it's working now.

Thanks to everyone for their answers and guidance.